# KIVY python: Slider inside ScrollView

Tags: slider, kivy

I created a scroll view in which i put some labels and 2 sliders.
The scroll works perfectly, but I can't change the slider's value with my mouse...
Please run this code and see:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Home(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=20, size_hint=(1, None))
        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))

        for i in range(50):
            if i%25==0:
                btn = Slider(min=1, max=10, value=4)
            else:
                btn = Label(text=str(i), color=(0,0,0,1), size=(32, 32), size_hint=(1, None))
            self.layout.add_widget(btn)

        self.scrll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, .6), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
        self.scrll.add_widget(self.layout)
        self.add_widget(self.scrll)

class MyAppli(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return Home()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay when you work with slider you shall redefine the on_touch_down, on_touch_up and on_touch_move method to handle those events:

-**main.py :**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class Home(BoxLayout):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(Home, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.b = []
      self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=5, spacing=20, size_hint=(1, None))
      self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))

      for i in range(50):
         if i % 25 == 0:
            self.b.append(MySlider(min=1, max=10, value=4, height=32, size_hint=(1, None)))
         else:
            self.b.append(Label(text=str(i), color=(0,0,0,1), height=32, size_hint=(1, None)))
         self.layout.add_widget(self.b[i])

      self.scrll = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, .6), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
      self.scrll.add_widget(self.layout)
      self.add_widget(self.scrll)

   def update(self, *args):
      for i in range(50):
         if i % 25 == 0:
            self.b[i].begin = self.b[i].pos[0]
            self.b[i].len = self.b[i].size[0]


class MySlider(Slider):

       def on_touch_down(self, touch):
          if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             super(MySlider, self).on_touch_down(touch)

       def on_touch_up(self, touch):
          if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             super(MySlider, self).on_touch_up(touch)

       def on_touch_move(self, touch):
          if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             super(MySlider, self).on_touch_move(touch)

class MyAppli(App):

   def build(self):
      Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
      return Home()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyAppli().run()
```

-**some outputs :**
[image: first]
[image: second]

I hope this helps !

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and when I click on the slider's blue circle, it moves some 50 pixels to the left with no slide effect.

Comment: It works now. Good ! by chance, do you know how to make sure that the slider moves even when we keep clicking, and that we get out of the slider's horizontal line ? i don't know if you see what i mean, but never mind ;:)